# Is it possible to trigger a specific lambda function from the AWS Kinesis stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, streaming, publish-subscribe, amazon-kinesis

Is it possible to trigger a specific lambda function from the AWS Kinesis stream?

I have multiple lambda functions (CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE) which are subscribed to the kinesis stream, now I want to trigger only specific lambda function based on the data/event type.

Is it possible? If not what is the better architecture/way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you can't do this. There are generally two ways to overcome this:

1. Connect your stream to one lambda function. The function will receive all records from the stream and **dispatch them to other functions**. The dispatch can be direct, or through dedicated SQS queues for example.

```
                   /-----> SQS 1 ---> CREATE lambda
Kinesis---->Lambda ------> SQS 2 ---> UPDATE lambda
                   \-----> SQS 3 ---> DELETE lambda
```

2. Also use one function, but this time UPDATE, CREATE and DELETE code will be in the single function. So in the lambda handler function, you would use basic **if-then-else** conditions to invoke different code for UPDATE, CREATE and DELETE functionality.